# Using JS for client side validation before submitting form in JSF

Tags: javascript, validation, jsf

I'm trying to do some client side validation on my registration form. It's supposed to just stop the submit and display some text helping the user understand what went wrong.

This is my XHTML:

```
            <h:form>
                <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                    <h:outputLabel for="emailInput" value="Email"></h:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText type="text" class="form-control" id="emailInput"   value="#{signupBackingBean.email}" required="true"></p:inputText>
                    <small id="emailError1" class="form-text">Field is required</small>
                    <small id="emailError2" class="form-text">Not avalid emailadress</small>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                    <h:outputLabel for="usernameInput" value="Username"></h:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameInput"  value="#{signupBackingBean.username}" required="true">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="20"></f:validateLength>
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message for="@previous" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                    <h:outputLabel for="passwordInput" value="Password"></h:outputLabel>
                    <p:password class="form-control" id="passwordInput"  value="#{signupBackingBean.password}" match="passwordInput2" feedback="true" required="true" inline="true" ></p:password>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                    <h:outputLabel for="passwordInput2" value="Password Confirmation"></h:outputLabel>
                    <p:password class="form-control" id="passwordInput2"  value="#{signupBackingBean.password}" required="true"></p:password>
                    <p:message for="@previous" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mx-auto">
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto btn-block" onclick="return showErrorMessages()"  action="#{signupBackingBean.add}" value="Register" ></h:commandButton>
                </div>
            </h:form>
```

JS

```
var email = document.getElementById("emailInput");

function showErrorMessages() {
        document.getElementById("emailError1").style.display = inline;
}
```

CSS:

```
#emailError1{
    display: none;
}
```

The plan is to trigger the Primeface validation (can't be null) and make the description text inline. I am however uncertain on how to do this. Right now I'm just trying to connect it to the submit commandButton, but id its easier to do earlier that will also work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know that PrimeFaces has built-in client-side validation?

Comment: Yeah, but since I want to display the "small" text attribute rather than a message I thought it would be easier to use JS.

Comment: 1: it is a small 'element' (not an attribute) 2: using something like this is uncommon (use css for styling) 3:using a undefined/unclear id for required and validation is weird... effectively making this unnecessary  complex unclear solution.

Comment: Okey, thanks! Basically the only thing i want to do is check the content of the input when I press submit, and display the appropriate message. Dosen't feel like it should be that hard?

Comment: That is what PrimeFaces client-side validation does

Comment: You have to  `....style.display = "inline"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a simple syntax error. When using JS to set style attributes the attributes, such as inline in this case, have to be in the form of string. So what I had to do was to change my JS file to:

```
function showErrorMessages() {
        document.getElementById("emailError1").style.display = "inline";
}
```